# Publisher and Location not printing when DOI is given

Tags: biblatex, koma-script, apa6, scrreprt

I'm writing a thesis using APA 6th citation style with biblatex. However, when I'm trying to cite a book with DOI *and* Location/Publisher, only the DOI is printed.

Here's my code:

```latex
%Dokumentenkopf
\documentclass[
    paper=A4,
    pagesize=auto
    12pt,
    ngerman,
    usegeometry,
    oneside,
    headinclude=false,
    footinclude=true,
    BCOR=0mm,
    DIV=calc,
    parskip=onehalf,
    bibliography=totocnumbered,
]{scrreprt}

%UTF8 und T1 Fontencoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Schriftart und Stil
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

%Pakete
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa6,apamaxprtauth=5]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=35mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[printonlyused, smaller]{acronym}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[section=chapter, numberedsection=false, acronym, nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\begin{filecontents}{oekonomie.bib}
@book{El-Richani2016,
    author = {given=Sarah, family=El-Richani},
    doi = {10.1057/978-1-137-60183-4},
    edition = {},
    language = {english},
    location = {New York},
    publisher = {Palgrave Macmillan},
    subtitle = {Anatomy of a System in Perpetual Crisis},
    title = {The Lebanese Media},
    year = {2016},
}
@book{Fuchs2021,
    author = {given=Christian, family=Fuchs},
    doi = {10.36198/9783838555003},
    edition = {2., vollständig überarbeitete Auflage},
    language = {ngerman},
    location = {Tübingen},
    publisher = {UVK Verlag},
    subtitle = {Eine Einführung},
    title = {Soziale Medien und die Kritische Theorie},
    year = {2021},
}
\end{filecontents}

\makenoidxglossaries

%Einbindung
\addbibresource{oekonomie.bib}
\input{siglen.tex}

\begin{document}
\cite{Fuchs2021} und \cite{El-Richani2016} belegen, dass...

\printbibliography

\end{document
```

It looks like this:

[image: Source1]
[image: Source2]

How can I change it so the location and publisher are no longer omitted when the source has a DOI printed?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Do you want to make this change because you need to fix an implementation error in biblatex's `apa6` style, or do you want to deviate deliberately from the (otherwise correct) `apa6` style?

Comment: @Mico I assume that everything's correct with the apa6 sytle, it's just that our professor requires us to include location and publisher with every source cited, even with a given doi

Comment: Thanks for your response. I suppose that, as a stop-gap measure, you could hand-edit the entries in question and change the `doi` field to a `note` field, i.e., change `doi = {10.36198/9783838555003},` to `note = {doi: \url{https://doi.org/10.36198/9783838555003}},`. Hopefully, somebody else will come up with a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The definition of the `location+publisher` bibmacro in `apa6.bbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/b0ffa503ae8019e0134172d29bb14be4a41d74d3/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/bbx/apa6.bbx#L2113-L2127) has a guard not to print anything if the `doi` is given. That test can be removed as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa6,apamaxprtauth=5]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xurl}

\renewbibmacro*{location+publisher}{%
  \printlist[default][1-1]{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{El-Richani2016,
    author    = {given=Sarah, family=El-Richani},
    doi       = {10.1057/978-1-137-60183-4},
    language  = {english},
    location  = {New York},
    publisher = {Palgrave Macmillan},
    subtitle  = {Anatomy of a System in Perpetual Crisis},
    title     = {The Lebanese Media},
    year      = {2016},
}
@book{Fuchs2021,
    author    = {given=Christian, family=Fuchs},
    doi       = {10.36198/9783838555003},
    edition   = {2., vollständig überarbeitete Auflage},
    language  = {ngerman},
    location  = {Tübingen},
    publisher = {UVK Verlag},
    subtitle  = {Eine Einführung},
    title     = {Soziale Medien und die Kritische Theorie},
    year      = {2021},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Fuchs2021} und \cite{El-Richani2016} belegen, dass...

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Fuchs, C. (2021). Soziale Medien und die Kritische Theorie: Eine Einführung (2., vollständig überarbeitete Auflage). Tübingen: UVK Verlag. doi:10.36198/9783838555003 El-Richani, S. (2016). The Lebanese Media: Anatomy of a System in Perpetual Crisis. New York: Palgrave Macmillan. doi:10.1057/978-1-137-60183-4]